# Trouble finding out what is creating virtual network devices

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

So for some reason I have a bunch of virtual network devices named `br-XXXXXXXXXXXX` and I have no idea what is creating them.

```
user@device:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp59s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-3c6d01bee8c8: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6b:d1:a7:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-3c6d01bee8c8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-4fee1a53fcc2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:8a:d4:10:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-4fee1a53fcc2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
.
.
.
11: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:31:67:1d:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I'd like to remove theses virtual devices as they cause some network issues on my setup due to occupying `172.XX.0.0/16` subnets.

I already tried deleting all of these virtual devices individually with `sudo ip link delete <devicename>` but they just re-appear after reboot.

Happening on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Desktop)

Comment: Are you using any kind of VPN?

Comment: Yes. I have two OpenVPN configurations as well as my university VPN managed via NetworkManager which I use on a semiregular basis. I was not connected to a VPN when running `ip a` though and there are more `br-XXXXXXXXXXXX` than I have VPN configurations saved.

Comment: They can create virtual devices, I do not know if that is the case here but something to look at.